# Exclude zero from JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I have an `JFormattedTextField` created by

```
JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance);
```

I would like to augment its behaviour, so that if the user 
enters a zero and the field loses focus, it reacts exactly as if the user had entered e.g. "foo".

Using an `InputVerifier` somehow wrecked the reverting behaviour, and using a custom subclass of `DecimalFormat` did not revert when zero was entered, but instead cleared the field.
(By zero I mean, anything that parses to `BigDecimal.ZERO`.)

The code I used:

```
new DecimalFormat(){
{
    setParseBigDecimal(true);
}
public Number parse(String txt, ParsePosition pos){
     BigDecimal num = (BigDecimal) super.parse(txt, pos);
     if(num == null || num.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0)
          return null;
     else return num;
}
```

Zero was not accepted then, but the field only reverted on letters entered.

Comment: "*if the user enters a zero*" Anywhere ins the string, or just `0`?

Comment: Edited: Anything that parses to `BigDecimal.ZERO`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting something similar to the code by @user1803551 into a `PropertyChangeListener` worked even better - before, there was an issue with hitting "return" when there was a default button in the form - it would receive "action performed" without the user having to change the input value. Plus, we get by without an additional variable.

```
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat();
format.setParseBigDecimal(true);
JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(format):
ftf.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getPropertyName().equals("value"))
            if ( ((BigDecimal) evt.getNewValue()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) ==0 )
                ftf.setValue(evt.getOldValue());
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `FocusListener` to do a similar check to what is done internally:

```
JFormattedTextField ftf = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
ftf.addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {

        Object lastValid = ftf.getValue();
        try {
            ftf.commitEdit();
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            ftf.setValue(lastValid);
        }
        Object newValue = ftf.getValue();
        if (newValue instanceof Long)
            if ((Long) newValue == 0l)
                ftf.setValue(lastValid);
    }
});
```

#### Notes on this approach:

- A `JFormattedTextField` has a `focusLostBehavior` which instructs what to do on focus lost. I assumed it will always be `COMMIT_OR_REVERT` (the default).
- Be careful if you registered a `PropertyChangeListener` to the text field, as I did not handle firing its events carefully. While inputs which can't be parsed will "immediately" be reverted (and not fire a `PropertyChangeEvent` event), a value which is parsed to `0` will first be committed (and fire a `PropertyChangeEvent`) and only then reverted (firing a `PropertyChangeEvent` again).

#### Notes on other approaches:

- While I think this is the most direct approach, there are almost certainly other ways to accomplish this which involve extending and overriding some methods. The hierarchy from the text field itself to the format chosen for it can be a bit complicated and modification can be done in some of the steps, though care should be taken to not break anything.
- Input verification can also work, but it behaves differently - it holds the focus until the input is verified, instead of allowing its loss and reverting. It is ultimately the programmer's choice.

Comment: Your way works, thanks. But I still don't understand why a custom Format doesn't.

Comment: It can I think, it just needs to be done carefully. My approach is akin to putting a patch over a hole instead of sewing it.